# Why a use of undeclared identifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why does my code say I'm using an undeclared identifier with 'hero' in shootAt in the line fourth from the end.

```
#import "GameplayLayer.h"
#import "Ship.h"
#import "MainCharacter.h"
#import "GameOverLayer.h"
int screenHeight;
int screenWidth;
@implementation GameplayLayer


-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        screenHeight = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] screenSize].height;
        screenWidth = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] screenSize].width;
        MainCharacter * hero = [[MainCharacter alloc] init];
        [self addChild: hero];
        hero.position = ccp(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/10);
        Ship * ship1 = [[Ship alloc] init];
        [self addChild: ship1];
        numEnemies++;
        ship1.position = ccp(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2);
    }
    return self;
    [self scheduleUpdate];
}

-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{

    KKInput * input = [KKInput sharedInput];
    CGPoint touchPosition = [input locationOfAnyTouchInPhase:KKTouchPhaseBegan]; 
    if (touchPosition.x != 0.0 || touchPosition.y != 0.0)
    {
        [hero shootAt: ccp(screenWidth/2, screenHeight)];
    }
}    
@end
```

Comment: If you don't understand this you need to lay off of Objective-C for awhile and practice with Java or C.  (The way you declared screenHeight and screenWidth is really bad.)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I think this is the problem of scope of variable, You declared 
        **hero**
in your 
        **init Method** 
and trying to access this variable in
       **update Method** (So hero is a local variable for init Method and undeclared for Update Method).

Update your code Like this, If you want a global Access of 
**hero** object,

```
    int screenHeight;
    int screenWidth;
    MainCharacter * hero;
```

And then initialize it in your init Method and access it in all other methods of same class.

Comment: Although you're right about the problem, I don't think "use more global variables" is great advice to offer someone new to programming.

Comment: Are you suggesting using global variables instead of adding property to the class instance or something similar?

Comment: That is a terrible suggestion (though it's already terrible that two global variables have been used).

Answer (score 3):

Because `hero` is local variable defined in the constructor and hence not visible in other methods.

Comment: It's not just that it's "not visible" -- it doesn't even *exist* anywhere else.